# In Alexa, how do I define slot defaults in my Intent code?

Tags: go, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have one intent in my lambda function. I am trying to fill 4 slots, 3 of which are required. In my tests it seems like I have to set the Assignee field to a default or something fails in my actual handler which happens after the else statement below. Here's how I'm currently defining the defaults:

if strings.ToUpper(request.DialogState) == "STARTED" {

```
        log.Println("DialogState == STARTED")
        // Pre-fill slots: update the intent object with slot values for which
        // you have defaults, then return Dialog.Delegate with this updated intent
        // in the updatedIntent property.
        slots := make(map[string]alexa.IntentSlot)
        slots["Summary"] = alexa.IntentSlot{
            Name:               "Summary",
            Value:              "",
            ConfirmationStatus: "NONE",
        }
        slots["TicketType"] = alexa.IntentSlot{
            Name:               "TicketType",
            Value:              "",
            ConfirmationStatus: "NONE",
        }
        slots["Project"] = alexa.IntentSlot{
            Name:               "Project",
            Value:              "",
            ConfirmationStatus: "NONE",
        }
        slots["Assignee"] = alexa.IntentSlot{
            Name:               "Assignee",
            Value:              "tcheek",
            ConfirmationStatus: "NONE",
        }
        i := &alexa.Intent{
            Name:               "OpenTicketIntent",
            ConfirmationStatus: "NONE",
            Slots:              slots,
        }
        response.AddDialogDirective("Dialog.Delegate", "", "", i)
        response.ShouldSessionEnd = false
        log.Println("DialogState has exited STARTED")

    } else if strings.ToUpper(request.DialogState) != "COMPLETED" {

        log.Println("DialogState == IN PROGRESS")
        // return a Dialog.Delegate directive with no updatedIntent property.
        response.ShouldSessionEnd = false
        response.AddDialogDirective("Dialog.Delegate", "", "", nil)
        log.Println("DialogState has exited IN PROGRESS")

    } else {
```

I have also tried setting just the Assignee field as a default, like this:

```
    slots := make(map[string]alexa.IntentSlot)

        slots["Assignee"] = alexa.IntentSlot{
            Name:               "Assignee",
            Value:              "tcheek",
            ConfirmationStatus: "NONE",
        }
        i := &alexa.Intent{
            Name:               "OpenTicketIntent",
            ConfirmationStatus: "NONE",
            Slots:              slots,
        }
        response.AddDialogDirective("Dialog.Delegate", "", "", i)
```

In this scenario I get the following lambda function response in the simulator:

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "Dialog.Delegate",
                    "updatedIntent": {
                        "name": "OpenTicketIntent",
                        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                        "slots": {
                            "Assignee": {
                                "name": "Assignee",
                                "value": "tcheek",
                                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession": false
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that once I ask it to open a bug ticket (which maps to the intent with the "Open a {ticketType} ticket" utterance), it gives the response that "There was a problem with the requested skill's response".

Am I wrong to think that setting defaults is necessary? Am I setting defaults incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge in response, u need to include all slots. As here the intent name and slots match then only you'll get the correct response

Comment: This is not an answer and it is unclear. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)